# After buy a giftcard I got blank screen in success page

Tags: magento-1.9, onestepcheckout, gift-card

If I add 'Gift Card' in cart I get empty/blank page on success page without footer.

It happens only if I add gift card and there is no errors in logs.

How can I fix this?

Comment: check php error_log file. it may me fatal error.  php are are store in mostly /var/log/httpd/error_log.log

Comment: logs is empty, and, when I put die(); at the end of the success page, i can see it is loadded, .. thank you order etc..., but sems to be redirected to other view, I dont know how to test that

Comment: fatal error are not stored in magento. check error_log. Also it is redirect to some other page. shall i know giftcard order is placed?